# iOS: Instruments hangs for App launch template for simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, instruments

When I try to use the App Launch profiling to understand the launch time activity using the simulator, it hangs.

It exactly hangs when I start recording, a screen saying

> "Analsying.. Inhibiting Data Aquistion"

is shown. Nothing happens then. How to fix that?